# Есть программа по считыванию данных из текстового файла.Необходимо реализовать метод по выводу информации по возрасту

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UsersRepository usersRepository = new UsersRepositoryFileImpl("users.txt");
        List<User> users = usersRepository.findByAge(27);


        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.getAge() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.isWorker());
        }

        User user = new User("Игорь", 33, true);
        usersRepository.save(user);
    }
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isWorker;

    public User(String name, int age, boolean isWorker) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isWorker = isWorker;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isWorker() {
        return isWorker;
    }

    public void setWorker(boolean worker) {
        isWorker = worker;
    }
}

public interface UsersRepository {
    List<User> findAll();
    void save(User user);
    List<User> findByAge(int age);
    List<User> findByIsWorkerIsTrue();
}

public class UsersRepositoryFileImpl implements UsersRepository {

    private String fileName;

    public UsersRepositoryFileImpl(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        // объявили переменные для доступа
        Reader reader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            // создали читалку на основе файла
            reader = new FileReader(fileName);
            // создали буферизированную читалку
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            // прочитали строку
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            // пока к нам не пришла "нулевая строка"
            while (line != null) {
                // разбиваем ее по |
                String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
                // берем имя
                String name = parts[0];
                // берем возраст
                int age = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                // берем статус о работе
                boolean isWorker = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[2]);
                // создаем нового человека
                User newUser = new User(name, age, isWorker);
                // добавляем его в список
                users.add(newUser);
                // считываем новую строку
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } finally {
            // этот блок выполнится точно
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    // пытаемся закрыть ресурсы
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    // пытаемся закрыть ресурсы
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
        }

        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        Writer writer = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            bufferedWriter.write(user.getName() + "|" + user.getAge() + "|" + user.isWorker());
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findByAge(int age) {
        List<User> users = findAll();
        // TODO: реализовать
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findByIsWorkerIsTrue() {
        // TODO: реализовать
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В существующей реализации репозитория должен быть некий метод или поле, которые возвращают список всех пользователей:

```java
public interface UsersRepository {
    List<User> findAll();
    List<User> findbyAge(int age);
}
```

Релизовать такой метод можно при помощи цикла:

```java
public class UsersRepositoryFileImpl implements UsersRepository {
    @Override
    public List<User> findbyAge(int age) {
        List<User> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User u : findAll()) {
            if (u.getAge() == age) {
                filtered.add(u);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

Или используя более лаконичный Stream API

```
    @Override
    public List<User> findbyAge(int age) {
        return findAll().stream()
            .filter(u -> u.getAge() == age)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

точно не могу понять что именно вам нужно сделать но предположу что вам нужно отфильтровать колекцию в методе

```
@Override
public List<User> findByAge(int age) {
    List<User> users = findAll();
    // TODO: реализовать
    return null;
}
```

если да то все очень просто

```
@Override
public List<User> findByAge(int age) {
    List<User> users = findAll();
    users.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getAge == age)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return users;
}
```